# Database won't update using script

Tags: python, postgresql

I'm trying to update the database to turn records to false if they are in the past.

I can run it and it works perfect using the query tool on the pgadmin.

I get no errors when I run the script and I get a message that the query has run successfully.

But the database won't update

This is my code:

```
 def connect_db(self):
        event_over = datetime.now()

    try:
        # Creating a cursor object using the cursor() method
        cursor = self.connection().cursor()
        postgres_insert_query = """UPDATE dashboard_calendarevent SET calendar_event_live=false WHERE 
        calendar_dates_end <= (%s); """

        cursor.execute(postgres_insert_query, (event_over,))
        self.connection().commit()

        count = cursor.rowcount
        print(count, "Records effected in Calendar table")

    except (Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error:
        print("Failed to update record into Calendar table because ", error)

    finally:
        # closing database connection.
        if self.connection():
            cursor.close()
            self.connection().close()
            print("PostgreSQL connection is closed")
```

This is the query that is run:

```
UPDATE dashboard_calendarevent SET calendar_event_live=false WHERE calendar_dates_end <= '2022-08-22 16:05:05.426078';
```

My message retuned:

```
14 Records effected in Calendar table
PostgreSQL connection is closed
```

There are 14 records to be changed but they are not updating.

This is a sample datetime in the Database 2022-08-19 15:30:00+00
And this is the time I am creating when the function is called. 2022-08-22 16:05:05.426078

There is no error logged in the files
I am connected to the correct database its reading the database as I know there is 14 records to be updated.

Comment: How do you know that the records are not updating?

Comment: 1) Do not use string interpolation(`f strings`) for parameter passing. Read this [Parameters](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries) and use the correct method. 2) Are you sure you are connecting to correct database or table in correct schema? 3) What does the Postgres log show when you do this? **Add information as update to question**.

Comment: Thanks I've changed the parameters, double checked the database and the log file doesn't log this. the other errors it does.

If the query works in the pgadmin, I think it must be in the query I am inserting even though I used the same one.

Comment: I've always had to use `curs.execute("UPDATE {} SET {} = {} WHERE id = {}".format('"my_table"', '"some_value"', "'" + the_value + "'", some_id))` to update my tables and values - thing is: you'd get an error from psycop and it'd force you to `rollback()` if your query was bad. I'm assuming you're running another query to check that those values were updated - `"""SELECT * FROM dashboard_calendarevent WHERE calendar_dates_end <= (%s) and calendar_event_live == false ; """` I believe is the right query?

Comment: Do not use .format @Shmack.  That is very dangerous.  Read the manual linked by Adrian above.

Comment: @Jeremy only when dealing with user input, no?

Comment: Can you share the code for your `connection()` method?

Comment: @Shmack it is dangerous all the time. You do this and then at some point user input is accepted and now you are wide open to SQL injection. Start with the safe method and use it all the time and then you are protected for now and the future.

Comment: If you are getting this '14 Records effected in Calendar table' then the query is hitting the database. The fact you are not seeing it in the logs means you don't have the configuration set up  for it. Read this [Error logging](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/runtime-config-logging.html) and in particular [What to log](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/runtime-config-logging.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-LOGGING-WHAT) especially `log_statement`. The other option is you don't see anything because you are updating to a different database then the one you looking at the log.